# Firebase: How can i use onDisconnect during logout?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase

How can i detect when a user logs out of firebase (either facebook, google or password) and trigger the onDisconnect method in the firebase presence system. .unauth() is not working. I would like to show a users online and offline status when they login and out, minimize the app (idle) - not just when the power off their device and remove the app from active applications on the device.

I'm using firebase simple login for angularjs/ angularfire

Im using code based off of this tutorial on the firebase site.
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-06-17-howto-build-a-presence-system.html

Please i need help with this!
Presence code:

```
var connectedRef = new Firebase(fb_connections);
var presenceRef = new Firebase(fb_url + 'presence/');
var presenceUserRef = new Firebase(fb_url + 'presence/'+ userID + '/status');
var currentUserPresenceRef =  new Firebase(fb_url + 'users/'+ userID + '/status');

connectedRef.on("value", function(isOnline) {
    if (isOnline.val()) {
      // If we lose our internet connection, we want ourselves removed from the list.
      presenceUserRef.onDisconnect().remove();
      currentUserPresenceRef.onDisconnect().set("<span class='balanced'>☆</span>");
      // Set our initial online status.
      presenceUserRef.set("<span class='balanced'>★</span>");
      currentUserPresenceRef.set("<span class='balanced'>★</span>");
    }

  });
```

Logout function:

```
var ref = new Firebase(fb_url);
var usersRef = ref.child('users');
service.logout = function(loginData) {
    ref.unauth();
    //Firebase.goOffline();  //not working
    loggedIn = false;
    seedUser = {};
    clearLoginFromStorage();
    saveLoginToStorage();
    auth.logout();


};
```

Comment: all the information is in the link you added... where exactly do you struggle?

Comment: Answer below. If that is not what you're looking for, include a minimal reproduction of your problem in your question. That's in general the best way to get help here on StackOverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5):

The `onDisconnect()` code that you provide, will run automatically on the Firebase servers when the connection to the client is lost. To force the client to disconnect, you can call [`Firebase.goOffline()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/gooffline.html).

Note that calling `unauth()` will simply sign the user out from the Firebase connection. It does not disconnect, since there might be data that the user still has access to.

**Update**

This works for me:

```
var fb_url = 'https://yours.firebaseio.com/';
var ref = new Firebase(fb_url);

function connect() {
  Firebase.goOnline();
  ref.authAnonymously(function(error, authData) {
    if (!error) {
      ref.child(authData.uid).set(true);
      ref.child(authData.uid).onDisconnect().remove();
    }
  });
  setTimeout(disconnect, 5000);
}

function disconnect() {
  ref.unauth();
  Firebase.goOffline();
  setTimeout(connect, 5000);
}

connect();
```

Comment: `Firebase.goOffline()` doesnt do anything either. I even tried pointing to the specific user reference on firebase ie `ref.goOffline()` and nothing. Also how do i indicate idle states? the example above uses jQuery and its timer function. I'm trying to write this for mobile and didnt want to include the bulky jquery script. thanks

Comment: This is too vague. Please provide a [*minimal*, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can see what you're doing.

Comment: As said: calling `unauth()` does *not* disconnect the user, nor should it. That is expected and intended behavior.

Comment: I know im passed that... goOffline doesnt work either

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/yivuza/edit?js,console. If you're having problems, try reproducing it in a jsbin/jsfiddle like I did here. Then you can link to it *and* include the **minimum** code in your question.

Comment: trying to adapt what you have to my code... would this work with a social login? maybe there is my problem...